# How to match only top level objects in swiftlint

Tags: regex, swiftlint

We have a swiftlint rule that basically enforces a prefix on our structs, classes and protocols (DC, DB, or DM depending on function). We want to match this only to top level objects, e.g. in the below example, I'd like only `TopLevel` and `SecondTopLevel` to throw an error:

```
class TopLevel {

    struct NotTopLevel {
        var test
    }

}

class SecondTopLevel {

}
```

Our current regex is the following: `(struct|class|protocol)\s(?!(func|DB|DC|DM))[^\n\r]+\{`, and this would match both `TopLevel` and `NotTopLevel`. I'd like to somehow give some regex (or some other swiftlint tool) to not match `NotTopLevel`, but to still match `TopLevel` and `SecondTopLevel`. Is this possible? Any ideas for how to do this?

The approach I've been trying to mimic, is to look for 0 or more previous class definitions before checking for our prefix, however, I'm running into issues trying to match an entire class one or more times before checking the prefix.

Comment: Can you assume your indentation is always consistent ?

Comment: Provided you cannot use the indentation to find the level of the declaration, there is no way to do this with a regular expression alone. Whatever regex you'll come up with, there will always be a set of declarations that will break it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(struct|class|protocol).*
```

so you match only the first struct class or protocol.